# Calculated column syntax error

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, error, calculated-column-formula

I use this formula for the date to appear after changing the data in the column (two answers). This formula works for me:

```
(IF([Approve Status]="Approved";TEXT(NOW();"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"))
```

But I need to use two answers in the formula, I try to combine them, but a syntax error appears

```
(IF([Approve Status]="Approved";TEXT();"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"));(IF([Approve Status]="Reject";TEXT();dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"))
```

Can u please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this formula:

```
=IF(OR([Approve Status]="Approved",[Approve Status]="Reject");TEXT(NOW();"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"))
```

**OR**:

```
=IF(OR([Approve Status]="Approved",[Approve Status]="Reject");TEXT(NOW();"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm");"")
```

Comment: Note: date value (`NOW()`) in calculated column will be evaluated every time list item is updated or calculated column formula settings changed.

Comment: It Works! Thank you very much. May I ask you one more question? Is it possible to write a  formula using calculated columns that puts the date not of their two choices, but if any text is entered?

Comment: Yes, you can write formula to check if "Approve Status" column is blank or not and then set date value accordingly. What is the column/data type of Approve Status?

Comment: Approve Status are choice of two items. Can u show me how formula should look like?

Comment: Did you allow fill-in values for this column? Or you will be adding more options/items in this choice column?

Comment: The first.I have two columns: approve status - it has a choice of two items. But there is another one in which the single line is the text that the user fills in and the date appears after that. did I make myself clear?

Comment: Can you create a new question with your requirements and column names? I will answer the question separately by adding some explanation.

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305194/answer-of-date-after-editing-the-column