# Answer of date after editing the column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have 2 columns, one of them "Approve Status" - it's a choice of two options, after selecting one of them column "Approve Date" setting the date by using this forvula `"IF(OR([Approve Status]="Approved";[Approve Status]="Reject");TEXT(NOW();"dd/mm/yyyy"))"`.

The second column "Comment" just are single text with a "Comment date" column, how "Comment Date" can be edited by formula after putting any text on "Comment"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a calculated column for "Comment Date" and use calculated formula like below:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK([Comment]));TEXT(NOW();"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"))
```

**OR**:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Comment]);"";TEXT(NOW();"dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm"))
```

Comment: Note: date value (`NOW()`) in calculated column will be evaluated every time list item is updated or calculated column formula settings changed.

Comment: It Works! Thank you! Maybe any idea how to make columns not be abble to edit after date appears?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot make column disabled (not editable) using SharePoint out of the box capabilities. You have to do it using Power Apps customized list form.

Comment: Thank you for answer anyway